# PHP DOM get text of blank page

Tags: php, tags

I get youtube videos this code is work.

```
<?php   
$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/".$user."/uploads?max-results=20";
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      $media = $entry->children('media', true);
      $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;   
      $url = clear($watch); 
//..............................
?>
```

But user is banned youtube get blank page

```
User account suspended
```

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MonsterJamVEVO/uploads?max-results=5

How to get text (User account suspended) Because is a don't have any tag. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags)?

Comment: i am using file_get_contents but i don't know parse document text blank page

Comment: If the page is blank you obviously don't have to remove the tags from it; could you share the code that you use to download the page contents?

Answer (score 0):

The response headers are indicative of the problem:

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

So, you would have to check for those errors:

```
$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/".$user."/uploads?max-results=20";

if (($contents = @file_get_contents($feedURL)) === false) {
    echo "$feedURL could not be loaded\n";
} else {
    $sxml = simplexml_load_string($contents);
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: i dont have an error. .$user. is variable in my sql. i want parse text "User account suspended" on this page: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MonsterJamVEVO/uploads?max-results=5